# How to replace a grid to list view via jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, view

I have a Pinterest style grid view and I need to replace the grid with the table view (as seen below) on a button click (and vice versa when grid button is clicked ).

I have looked it up but couldn't find any decent examples or documentation. So i'm not sure how to go about it. Any help is much appreciated.

**HTML: Buttons**

```
<a id="#grid"><i class="fa fa-th-large" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
<a id="#list"><i class="fa fa-list" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

**JS: Switch the data from grid to list and visa versa**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#list').click(function(event){event.preventDefault();$('.pinGrid .pin').addClass('list-items');});
    $('#grid').click(function(event){event.preventDefault();$('.pinGrid .pin').removeClass('list-items');$('.pinGrid .pin').addClass('');});
});
```

**HTML: Pinterest**

```
  <div class="child_vac pin" id="">
    <div class="pull-right intrest-box">
      <input type="checkbox" class="faChkRnd like" name=""></div>
     <p class="pull-left">date</p>
      <h2 class="job-title text-center">  </h2>
      <p class="info-text text-center" ><b></b></p><p class="box-requirements">

      </p>
      <div class="text-center">
        <p class="card-title"> <a href="#moreinfo"  data-id="" class="moreinfo">More Information</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/umr9hucj/3/)

Answer (score 1):

The ideal practice is to keep the HTML the same for both views, except for a single class of `masonry`or `table` on the container.

Use `display: table`, `display: table-row`, and `display: table-cell` CSS to trigger table styling.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. I just put that in for demonstrative purposes. :) Thanks for the help.